# Calculate time duration in seconds of single Date column, while group_by ID in R

Tags: r, loops, time, dplyr

Is there a way for R to group by ID, identify a 'break' in time, set this to 0, and then calculate time difference?

For instance:

```
                ID               TIME              
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM
                A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM               
                B                12/18/2019 4:14:13 AM
                B                12/18/2019 4:14:14 AM
```

Does anyone know of a way to find the time duration for A? Notice this is not a difftime problem. I performed a certain activity at 4:45:10 am, then again at 4:45:11 am. I then stopped this activity, and picked back up at 9:06pm. Is there code that can accurately group IDs, and then calculate time difference in seconds whilst setting a huge gap in the time to ‘0’ to avoid inaccurate values?

This is not the correct solution.

```
                       diff<- data %>%
                       mutate(diff = difftime(as.POSIXct(Endtime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), 
                       as.POSIXct(Starttime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), units = "secs"))
```

Outcome:

```
                ID               TIME                         Duration   
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM        1 sec
                A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM        
                A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM        0 sec                    
                B                12/18/2019 4:14:13 AM        1 sec
                B                12/18/2019 4:14:14 AM
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
 I will continue to research this. Thank you

Comment: Can you show the expected output in the post

Comment: Hello, I have added the expected output. I want to group by IDs, pair similar datetimes and take their duration. Any datetime that is of a different hour or minute within this ID will get assigned a value of 0.

Comment: Are you doing a cut if it is greater than 1 sec

Comment: I am assigning value to 0 if the hour and minute are not consecutive to the row above it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the 'TIME' to Datetime class with `mdy_hms` from `lubridate`, grouped by 'ID', check or the consecutive elements in 'TIME' by taking the difference in 'TIME' between adjacent elements using `difftime` (specify the `unit`), create a numeric index with `cumsum` add that also as grouping column to create the `diff`erence between 'TIME' elements as a new column 'Duration'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(TIME = mdy_hms(TIME)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%  
  group_by(grp = cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(TIME,
     lag(TIME, default = first(TIME)), TIME, unit = 'sec')) > 1), add = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Duration = if(n() == 1) NA_real_ else as.numeric(c(diff(TIME), 0))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  ID    TIME                Duration
#  <chr> <dttm>                 <dbl>
#1 A     2019-12-18 04:45:10        1
#2 A     2019-12-18 04:45:11        0
#3 A     2019-12-18 21:06:59       NA
#4 B     2019-12-18 04:14:13        1
#5 B     2019-12-18 04:14:14        0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), TIME = c("12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM", 
"12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM", "12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM", "12/18/2019 4:14:13 AM", 
"12/18/2019 4:14:14 AM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Hello Akrun, I keep getting: unexpected special %>%   am I needing format?

Comment: @TanishaHudson Have you loaded `library(dplyr)`

Comment: I think this works, I will thoroughly check it. As I am still learning, can you explain what the code is doing please?

Comment: @TanishaHudson. I updated the post with the description

Comment: ok yes, this works. Furthermore, I can set the NAs to any value I wish, correct?

Comment: @TanishaHudson. Yes, you can set it to any value.  I used `NA` because in your expected it was more like a blank `""` which is character and it would convert to character class

Comment: Thank you kindly- would I just substitute NA_Real for the value I want?

Comment: @TanishaHudson yes, I used `NA_real_` because the type from diff output is numeric